# Cannot save image in a folder that I created

Tags: c#, file, gdi+, openfiledialog, imaging

I'm currently creating an image resizing program with C# Windows Forms.
So, I make it overwrite existing images with resized images.
I also made a function that makes `Originals` folder and save originals images in it, in order that when I need original images I can use images in the folder.
Below is th

```
for (int k = 0; k < openFileDialog.FileNames.Length; k++)
{
   fileNames.Add(openFileDialog.FileNames[k]);

   using (Stream stream = File.OpenRead(fileNames[k]))
   {
       //System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Drawing.Image>
       selectedImages.Add(Image.FromStream(stream));
       resizedImages.Add(Image.FromStream(stream));                                                 
   }
   filesCount++;
}

for (int k = 0; k < filesCount; k++)
{
    string filePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileNames[k]);
    Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath + "\\Originals");

    string selectedFileName = filePath + "\\Originals\\" + Path.GetFileName(fileNames[k]);
    string resizedFileName = filePath + "\\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileNames[k]) + ".jpg";

    //GetImageFormat is my function that return ImageFormat. It has no problem.
    selectedImages[k].Save(selectedFileName, GetImageFormat(Path.GetExtension(fileNames[k])));
    resizedImages[k].Save(resizedFileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

The problem here is that `selectedImages[k].Save` emit GDI+ generic error although `resizedImages[k].Save` works completely fine.
I think it's because of the folder that I created but I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think it's because of the folder that I created but I can't find a
>   solution.

Wrong [`Directory.CreateDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.createdirectory?view=netframework-4.7.2) will throw an exception if it cant create it when it does not already exist.

---

So lets address the problems you have

- `\\Originals\\` don't do this, if you need a back slash use @`\Originals\`
- If you are going to combine a path, use [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_Path_Combine_System_String_System_String_)
- Don't use `for` when you can use a `foreach`
- there was no need to make so many lists and loops
- if you create an image you need to dispose it
- And the biggest one is, **do not** try to save a file over a file with an open file handle.

At times like this, you need to step back from your code and remove all the redundancy. Most of your code was absolutely not needed, and it makes your life harder to debug

```
foreach (var file in openFileDialog.FileNames)
{
   var name = Path.GetFileName(file);
   var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(file);
   var newPath = Path.Combine(path, "Originals");
   var newName = $"{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(name)}.jpg";

   Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);

   var newFullPath = Path.Combine(newPath, name);
   // why do anything fancy when you just want to move it
   File.Move(file, newFullPath);

   // lets open that file from there, so we don't accidentally cause the same 
   // problem again, then save it
   using (var image = Image.FromFile(newFullPath))
      image.Save(Path.Combine(path, newName), ImageFormat.Jpeg);  
}
```

Although i am not sure what your actual problem was, i am assuming it was the `GetImageFormat` method, or you were trying to overwrite a file with an open handle. However, in the spirit of what i think you are trying to achieve, this will probably just work

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to overwrite the existing file. That is not supported by the Image.Save method.

The solution is simple, delete the file before saving it again:

```
File.Delete(selectedFileName);
selectedImages[k].Save(selectedFileName, GetImageFormat(Path.GetExtension(fileNames[k])));
```